# Typcast a null pointer to char*

Tags: c, pointers, char, nullpointerexception

Suppose I have a `char* elem` that is supposed to hold a `char**`, such that `elem[0] = char**`, `elem[1...m]= <more chars>`. Is there a way I can put a null ptr within `char* elem`? When I try to set `elem = NULL`, it gives me a type error because NULL is an int.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wait, you have a char* vector and you want your vector to hold char pointers to other data? It's a bit confusing that is why I'm asking.

Comment: Do you maybe want to have a struct? Is this a linked list? Something like `struct my_struct { char ** next; char data[DATA_LENGTH]; }` ?

Comment: A `char *` should point to a `char`.  It should be a pointer to `char`.  It should not, in any way, hold a `char **`, although a `char **` points to a `char *` (when not null).  Moreover, if you declare `elem` as any sort of pointer, assigning `NULL` to it will give the appropriate null pointer constant, so I don't understand your last sentence.  Please edit this question to include the code you've written and more specifically what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a binary 0, try '\0'
That is null termination at the end of a string (char *)

Answer (score 1):

`char*` points to a `char`, not `char*`. Unless your architecture has 8-bit addresses or your characters are way wider than 8-bit, you can't possibly cram pointer into character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `NULL` vs. `0`, they are the same and mean null-pointer which is a different concept than arithmetic 0 or binary 0. Your problem is most likely with the definition of your array.

String case (pointer to char):

```
char *s;
s = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
s[0] = 'H';      /* set char */
s[1] = NULL;     /* not ok */
s[2] = '\0';     /* binary 0, end of string marker */
```

Pointer of pointer to char:

```
char **x;
x = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
x[0] = "Hello";  /* let it point to string */
x[1] = NULL;     /* let it point to nowhere */
x[2] = 0;        /* same thing as above */
x[3] = '\0';     /* bad, expects pointer to char not char */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plain `char* foo` variable then `foo[0]` will be of type `char` so you'll have to set it to `\0` (or `0`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the pointers mixed up.

```
char* - string
char ** - address of that string or an array of strings depending on your data
char *** - address of an array of strings.
```

Try re-reading your assignment maybe you got something wrong.

LE:
And what Jeromi mentioned in his comment works.

```
typedef struct{

char** some_data

}info;

char* info;
```

If you want some char** to be NULL as some point just initialize your info->some_data to NULL when you allocate memory.